# How to parse and convert HTML string in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have this XML string and would like to parse and traverse it

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1">Issue ID</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Abstract</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th colspan="1">Assigned To</th>
      <th>Estimate</th>
      <th colspan="1">Start Date</th>
      <th colspan="1">End Date</th>
      <th colspan="1">Actual</th>
      <th colspan="1">Milestones</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="highlight-blue" data-highlight-colour="blue">265884</td>
      <td class="highlight-blue" data-highlight-colour="blue"> </td>
      <td class="highlight-blue" data-highlight-colour="blue">Task 1</td>
      <td class="highlight-blue" data-highlight-colour="blue"> </td>
      <td class="highlight-blue" data-highlight-colour="blue"> </td>
      <td class="highlight-blue" data-highlight-colour="blue"> </td>
      <td class="highlight-blue" data-highlight-colour="blue"> </td>
      <td class="highlight-blue" data-highlight-colour="blue"> </td>
      <td class="highlight-blue" data-highlight-colour="blue"> </td>
      <td class="highlight-blue" data-highlight-colour="blue"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>QA</td>
      <td>Verify fix</td>
      <td>In-Progress</td>
      <td>Karl</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Feb 11</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>0.25</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>Feb 11: Change Code Review to "No Review Required"</li>
          <li>Feb 11: Requested SB for testing</li>
          <li>Feb 13: Still waiting for SB</li>
          <li>Feb 18: (need to follow up) -&gt; Done Re-requested SB copy</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to get the number of `<tr>`'s as well as do for-loop in the array to access each column. I looked into XmlReader but not quite sure how to use it without using a GridPanel.
Perhaps Ext.data.Store alone can achieve that, but I'm still not quite familiar with it and can't find any suitable methods here: http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.data.XmlReader

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Ext selector (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext-method-select).

Sample code for your case: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4pv

Comment: thanks for the code. but you have to render the html code in a Viewport first before you can use the Ext selector. that's similar to my workaround: have a hidden <div> somewhere, append the content of XML file there, then use the Ext selector. but i'm just wondering if there are other solutions.

Comment: Well if you want to traverse markup that is not rendered, can you maybe do it in backend?

Comment: If that is not the case you can use Ext.Element for DOM manipulation (it also has selector method): http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/?mobile=/api/Ext.Element